# How to connect Android Java App to MongoDB

Tags: java, android, database, mongodb

I try to use the Mongo DB atlas for my app. It works fine on the iOS side with MongoKitten.

On the Android side, I try to use the official driver.

No matter which version, my app crashed when trying to connect to the databaseL

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:          
      Ljavax/naming/directory/InitialDirContext;
        at com.mongodb.internal.dns.JndiDnsClient.createDnsDirContext(JndiDnsClient.java:73)
```

```
package fundamentals;

import com.mongodb.*;
import org.bson.BsonDocument;
import org.bson.BsonInt64;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.conversions.Bson;

import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

public class MongoClientConnectionExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Replace the placeholder with your Atlas connection string
        String uri = "<connection string>";

        // Construct a ServerApi instance using the ServerApi.builder() method
        ServerApi serverApi = ServerApi.builder()
               .version(ServerApiVersion.V1)
               .build();

        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
               .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(uri))
               .serverApi(serverApi)
               .build();

        // Create a new client and connect to the server
        try (MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings)) {
             MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("admin");
             try {
                 // Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
                 Bson command = new BsonDocument("ping", new BsonInt64(1));
                 Document commandResult = database.runCommand(command);
                 System.out.println("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to         
     MongoDB!");
             } catch (MongoException me) {
                 System.err.println(me);
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Version:

```
        implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.11.1'
```

Also, when installing, the following issue comes up:

```
2 files found with path
       'META-INF/native-image/org.mongodb/bson/native-image.properties'.
```

Which I solve by using

```
pickFirst 'META-INF/native-image/org.mongodb/bson/native-image.properties
```

Can anyone help me to solve these issues?

Comment: Here is a similar issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-3245